Permutations and rank
Suppose $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ are $m$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $n<m$, such that $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are linearly independent, and $v_{n+1}, \ldots, v_m$ are nonzero vectors.

I would like to characterize the permutations $\sigma\in S_m$ such that $v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(n)}$ are linearly independent.

The following are obvious:

If $\sigma(\{1, \ldots, n\}) \subset \{1, \ldots, n\}$, the set $\{v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(n)}\}$ is linearly independent.
If $v_i = e_i$ ($i = 1, \ldots, n$) is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the Euclidean scalar product satisfies $\langle v_p, v_i \rangle \neq 0$ for $p = n+1, \ldots, m$, then a permutation $\sigma$ can be chosen such that:
$$\sigma(\{1, \ldots, \widehat{i}, \ldots, n\}) \subset \{1, \ldots, \widehat{i}, \ldots, n\},\ \text{and}\ \sigma(i) = p.$$

Let $M = (\alpha_{ij})$ be the matrix of the vectors $v_{n+1}, \ldots, v_m$ expressed in terms of the basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$.

How can we characterize the permutations $\sigma \in S_m$ using the matrix $M$? Specifically, under what conditions on $M$ can we ensure that $v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(n)}$ are linearly independent?


This is actually a famous problem when you consider it in vector spaces over finite fields, instead of the real numbers. A set of vectors in $\mathbb F_q^n$ with $\mathbb F_q$ the finite field of order $q$ having the property that any subset of $n$ of these vectors is linearly independent (hence a basis) is called an arc. A famous result in finite geometry shows that arcs are equivalent to so-called linear MDS codes. For more information on the finite field case, you could take a look at this paper.
Let's return to the real case.
First of all, it is a bit overkill to look at permutations of the vectors $v_1, \dots, v_m$. If we choose $n$ of these vectors, say $v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(n)}$, then whether or not these vectors are linearly dependent doesn't depend on the order in which we write them, it only depends on the set of vectors. So it would be more natural to look at the subsets of $v_1, \dots, v_m$ of size $n$ which form a basis for $\mathbb R^n$.
A subset of $\{v_{i_1}, \dots, v_{i_n}\}$ of $n$ of these vectors will be linearly dependent if and only if there exists a hyperplane (i.e. a subspace of dimension $n-1$) that contains all of them. So a geometric way of characterizing which subsets of $n$ vectors form a basis is by looking at the intersections of the set $\{v_1, \dots, v_m\}$ with the hyperplanes of the space. In particular, any subset of size $n$ is a basis if and only each hyperplane contains at most $n-1$ of the vectors of $\{v_1, \dots, v_m\}$.
This is more or less the simplest way to phrase the problem.

This answer mainly addresses your second question.
Let $V\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ be the matrix of $v_{1},\ldots ,v_{m}$ as
columns, and partition it into the basis part $V_{1}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times
n}$ and the rest $V_{2}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times (m-n)}$. Then $V_{2}=V_{1}M$;
$M$ is $n\times (m-n)$ and its $(j-n)$th column comprises the coefficients
of $v_{1},\ldots ,v_{n}$ in the linear combination specifying $v_{j},$ $j>n$
. Let $P\in \{0,1\}^{m\times m}$ be the permutation matrix corresponding to
a permutation $\sigma $ that permutes columns of $V$ when postmultiplying
it. Partition $P$ conformably, then
$$
V=
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{1} & V_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
=V_{1}
\begin{bmatrix}
I & M
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
P_{11} & P_{12} \\ 
P_{21} & P_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
=V_{1}
\begin{bmatrix}
P_{11}+MP_{21} & P_{12}+MP_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and we are interested in the rank of $V_{1}(P_{11}+MP_{21})$, which is the
same as the rank of $P_{11}+MP_{21}$ since $V_{1}$ is nonsingular. (So
nothing is lost by assuming $v_{1},\ldots ,v_{n}$ is the canonical basis.)
For the first case where $\sigma \in (\{1,\ldots ,n\})\subseteq \{1,\ldots
,n\},$ $P_{11}$ is a nonsingular $n\times n$ permutation matrix, $P_{21}=0$,
and $P_{11}+MP_{21}=P_{11}$ has rank $n$.
Suppose now that exactly one of the $\sigma (1),\ldots ,\sigma (n)$ is not
in $\{1,\ldots ,n\}$. WLOG take $\sigma (1)=j>n$. Then $P_{j1}=1$; column 1
of $P_{11}$ is zero, and columns of $P_{21}$ except for column 1 are zero,
so $MP_{21}$ has the $(j-n)$th column of $M$ as its first column and the
rest of its columns are zero. That is, $P_{11}+MP_{21}$ is $P_{11}$ with its
first column replaced by the $(j-n)$th column of $M$.
Let $i$ be the one value of $\sigma (2),\ldots ,\sigma (n)$ that is not in $%
\{1,\ldots ,n\}$. Then the $i$th row of $P_{11}$ is zero. If the $(j-n)$th
column of $M$ has its corresponding entry zero, then the $i$th row of $
P_{11}+MP_{21}$ is zero and its rank is $n-1$; otherwise it is full rank.
Since $M_{i,j-n}=0$ indicates that the linear combination for $v_{j}$ does
not include $v_{i}$, the conclusion is that replacing $v_{1}$ with $v_{j}$
leads to full rank iff the l.c. for $v_{j}$ does not include $v_{i}$ where $i
$ is the omitted value in the image of $\sigma $.
Example: $n=4$, $m=7$, $\sigma =5132647$,
$$
V=
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -2 & 0 & 3 & -4 & 11 & -8 \\ 
-5 & 4 & -2 & -1 & -2 & -19 & 12 \\ 
0 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 7 & 5 & -12 \\ 
-3 & -3 & 4 & 0 & 9 & 4 & 8%
\end{bmatrix}
,~M=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 & -2 \\ 
-2 & -2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
-1 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$5132$ has first element $j=5$ not in $\{1,2,3,4\},$ and the omitted value
is $i=4$. $M_{i,j-n}=M_{41}\neq 0$ so $\{v_{5},v_{1},v_{3},v_{2}\}$ are
linearly independent. But for $\sigma =5142637$, $j=5$, $i=3$, $M_{31}=0$
and $\{v_{5},v_{1},v_{4},v_{2}\}$ are linearly dependent.
Consider now the case with two of  $\sigma (1),\ldots ,\sigma (n)$ not in $
\{1,\ldots ,n\},$ say $j_{1},j_{2}$, with the omitted values being $
i_{1},i_{2}.$ The determinant of $P_{11}+MP_{21}$ simplifies to $\pm $ the
determinant of the entries of $M$ lying in rows $i_{1,}i_{2}$ and columns $
j_{1}-n,j_{2}-n$.  To see this, permute these rows and columns to be in the
leading diagonal block; the other diagonal block is then a permutation
matrix (the remainder of $P_{11},$ with determinant $\pm 1).$ The
off-diagonal blocks are a zero matrix and the
remaining rows and columns of $M$. The determinant is the product of the
determinant of the diagonal blocks, and is zero when the leading diagonal
block is zero. The vectors are linearly independent when the determinant is
non-zero ($P_{11}+MP_{21}$ has rank $n$). For the $M$ in the example, the
only case where the vectors will be dependent is for $i_{1}=1$, $i_{2}=2$, $
j_{1}=6$, $j_{2}=7$, because the $M(\{ 1,2 \}, \{2,3 \})$ submatrix $
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -2 \\ 
-2 & 2%
\end{bmatrix}
$ is the only $2\times 2$ submatrix with determinant zero. This occurs for
example for  $\sigma =6437125$.
General procedure:
Let $N=\{1,\ldots ,n\}$, $\sigma ^{\prime }=\{\sigma
(1),\ldots ,\sigma (n)\},$ $S_{j}=\sigma ^{\prime }\setminus N$, $
S_{i}=N\setminus \sigma ^{\prime }$, $S_{j}^{^{\prime }}=\{p:~p=j-n,~j\in
S_{j}\}$ and $k=|S_{i}|=|S_{j}|=|S_{j}^{\prime }|$. $P_{11}$ has nonzero
columns indexed by $\overline{S_{i}}=\{p:\sigma (p)\in N\}$ where the
overbar indicates the complement with respect to $N$. These columns have
entry 1 in row $\sigma (p)$, and the same columns in $P_{21}$ and $MP_{21}$
are zero. WLOG we permute these to be the last $n-k$ columns of $
P_{11}+MP_{21}$. The remaining $k$ columns (now first) of $P_{11}$ are zero
but the same columns in $P_{21}$ are nonzero, with entry 1 in rows $
S_{j}^{\prime }$. The product $MP_{21}$ has these $k$ columns equal to the
columns of $M$ indexed by $S_{j}^{\prime }$, and this is true also for the
sum $P_{11}+MP_{21}$.
The$\ \,k$ rows in $P_{11}$ indexed by $S_{i}$ are zero, and are zero also
in the last $n-k$ columns of $P_{11}+MP_{21}$. We permute these rows in $
P_{11}+MP_{21}$ to be the first $k$ rows, leading to the final block form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
M(S_{i},S_{j}^{\prime }) & 0 \\ 
M(\overline{S_{i}},S_{j}^{\prime }) & P_{11}(\overline{S_{i}},\overline{S_{i}
})
\end{bmatrix}%
$$
where $P_{11}(\overline{S_{i}},\overline{S_{i}})$ is a permutation matrix
with determinant $\pm 1$. The determinant of this matrix is zero if and only
if $|M(S_{i},S_{j}^{\prime })|=0$. The column and row permutations to get
this form from the original $P_{11}+MP_{21}$ preserve the rank and the
magnitude of the determinant (but not necessarily its sign). The vectors are
therefore linearly independent for the given permutation if and only if $
|M(S_{i},S_{j}^{\prime })|\neq 0$.
By reversing this procedure it is evident that given any square submatrix $M(S_{i},S_{j}^{\prime })$ of $M$, a (non-unique) corresponding permutation can be found that leads to linearly independent (resp. dependent) vectors if the determinant of the submatrix is nonzero (resp. zero). Specifically, add $n$ to the values in $S_{j}^{\prime }$ to get $S_{j}$, then $\sigma^{\prime }$ will contain these and $\overline{S_{i}}$ in any order, with the others in $\sigma (n+1),\ldots ,\sigma (m)$ in any order.
